# Make an alarm with CloudTime value?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-uno-wifi

I am trying to make an alarm clock with an Arduino R4 Wifi, so I made a variable connected to iOT which is a CloudTime value. The thing is that I don't understand how to get this value in my code? I tried `hour = alarm1.getHour()` but it didn't work. I can't find any informations on the internet, so it would help me a lot if someone here knows how to get the value of the **CloudTime** variable. Thanks!

Here's my full code :
(The declaration of the time is right at the end of the code.)

```c
/*
  Sketch generated by the Arduino IoT Cloud Thing "Untitled"

  Arduino IoT Cloud Variables description

  The following variables are automatically generated and updated when changes are made to the Thing

  int day;
  CloudTime alarm1;

  Variables which are marked as READ/WRITE in the Cloud Thing will also have functions
  which are called when their values are changed from the Dashboard.
  These functions are generated with the Thing and added at the end of this sketch.
*/

#include "thingProperties.h"
#include "RTC.h"
#include "Arduino_LED_Matrix.h"

ArduinoLEDMatrix matrix;

byte Time[8][12] = {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};

byte  Digits  [5][30]{                                                                 
{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
};                                   


int currentSecond;
boolean secondsON_OFF = 1;
int hours, minutes, seconds, year, dayofMon;
String dayofWeek, month;

void displayDigit(int d, int s_x, int s_y){
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
      Time[i+s_x][11-j-s_y] = Digits[j][i+d*3];   
    
  matrix.renderBitmap(Time, 8, 12);
}


DayOfWeek convertDOW(String dow){
  if (dow == String("Mon")) return DayOfWeek::MONDAY;
  if (dow == String("Tue")) return DayOfWeek::TUESDAY;
  if (dow == String("Wed")) return DayOfWeek::WEDNESDAY;
  if (dow == String("Thu")) return DayOfWeek::THURSDAY;
  if (dow == String("Fri")) return DayOfWeek::FRIDAY;
  if (dow == String("Sat")) return DayOfWeek::SATURDAY;
  if (dow == String("Sun")) return DayOfWeek::SUNDAY;
}

Month convertMonth(String m){
 if (m == String("Jan")) return Month::JANUARY;
  if (m == String("Feb")) return Month::FEBRUARY;
  if (m == String("Mar")) return Month::MARCH;
  if (m == String("Apr")) return Month::APRIL;
  if (m == String("May")) return Month::MAY;
  if (m == String("Jun")) return Month::JUNE;
  if (m == String("Jul")) return Month::JULY;
  if (m == String("Aug")) return Month::AUGUST;
  if (m == String("Sep")) return Month::SEPTEMBER;
  if (m == String("Oct")) return Month::OCTOBER;
  if (m == String("Nov")) return Month::NOVEMBER;
  if (m == String("Dec")) return Month::DECEMBER;
}

void getCurTime(String timeSTR,String* d_w,int* d_mn, String* mn,int* h,int* m,int* s,int* y){
  
  *d_w = timeSTR.substring(0,3);
  *mn = timeSTR.substring(4,7);
  *d_mn = timeSTR.substring(8,11).toInt();
  *h = timeSTR.substring(11,13).toInt();
  *m = timeSTR.substring(14,16).toInt();
  *s = timeSTR.substring(17,19).toInt();
  *y = timeSTR.substring(20,24).toInt();

}

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Initialize Matrix LEDs
  matrix.begin();
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500);

  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);

  /*
     The following function allows you to obtain more information
     related to the state of network and IoT Cloud connection and errors
     the higher number the more granular information you’ll get.
     The default is 0 (only errors).
     Maximum is 4
  */
  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();
  RTC.begin();
  String timeStamp = __TIMESTAMP__;
  getCurTime(timeStamp,&dayofWeek,&dayofMon,&month,&hours,&minutes,&seconds,&year);
  RTCTime startTime(dayofMon, convertMonth(month) , year, hours, minutes, seconds, convertDOW(dayofWeek), SaveLight::SAVING_TIME_ACTIVE);
  RTC.setTime(startTime);
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  // Your code here
  RTCTime currentTime;

  // Get current time from RTC
  RTC.getTime(currentTime);

  if (currentTime.getSeconds()!=currentSecond){
    secondsON_OFF ?  secondsON_OFF = 0 : secondsON_OFF = 1;
    displayDigit((int)(currentTime.getHour()/10),0,0 );
    displayDigit((currentTime.getHour()%10)+1,4,0 );
    displayDigit((int)(currentTime.getMinutes()/10),1,6 );
    displayDigit(currentTime.getMinutes()%10,5,6 );
    Time[0][2]=secondsON_OFF;
    Time[0][4]=secondsON_OFF;
    currentSecond=currentTime.getSeconds();
    matrix.renderBitmap(Time, 8, 12);
    Serial.println(secondsON_OFF);
  }

  delay(1000);

}



/*
  Since Day is READ_WRITE variable, onDayChange() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onDayChange()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon Day change
  
}

/*
  Since Alarm1 is READ_WRITE variable, onAlarm1Change() is
  executed every time a new value is received from IoT Cloud.
*/
void onAlarm1Change()  {
  // Add your code here to act upon Alarm1 change
  CloudTime newAlarm = alarm1;
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing all your code, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces *only* what you're trying to solve.